# Obter data/horario atual AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, datetime, data

Preciso exibir na página a data atual seguida do horário atual,
Segue oque eu tenho feito até agora, somente preciso exibir o horário se continuar como está, segue código:

```
 function dataHoje() {
            var data = new Date();
            var dia = data.getDate();
            var mes = data.getMonth() + 1;
            var ano = data.getFullYear();
            return [dia, mes, ano].join('/');
        }
```

Html:

```
 <span class="pull-left time-label">
```

Está sendo exibido: 15/4/2016 -

Somente preciso da hora, deste jeito: 15/4/2016 - 14h55

Alguém pode ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Angular possui diversos [Filtros](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) para formatar os dados. Os filtros podem ser adicionados às expressões usando o caractere pipe `|`, seguido de um filtro.
No seu caso, você precisa utilizar o filtro [date](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

Na sua página você deve chamar o filtro dessa forma:

```
{{ data| date:'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'}}
```

Alguns filtros aceitam parâmetros, o filtro date é um deles. No exemplo passamos como parâmetro o formato da data.

Segue um exemplo no [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Om6e4lKW24ti8fGHcMgj?p=preview).

Answer (score 1):

Segue resposta:

```
 function dataHoje() {
     var data = new Date();
     var dia = data.getDate();
     var mes = data.getMonth() + 1;
     if (mes < 10) {
        mes = "0" + mes;
    }
    var ano = data.getFullYear();
    var horas = new Date().getHours();
    if (horas < 10) {
        horas = "0" + horas;
    }
    var minutos = new Date().getMinutes();
    if (minutos < 10) {
        minutos = "0" + minutos;
    }
    var result = dia+"/"+mes+"/"+ano+" - "+horas + "h" + minutos;
    return result;
}
$('.time-label').html(dataHoje());
```

Comment: Se você for usar javascript puro, está é a forma. Agora como você está usando o Angular, você pode usar as ferramentas que ele te oferece. E uma pergunta, por que você está usando o jQuery para atualizar os dados da view?

Comment: Dei o exemplo de javascript puro, porém acabei de descobrir o Moment.js que facilitou e muito.. Segue link: http://momentjs.com/

Comment: Olha minha resposta. O Angular dá suporte nativo a formato de datas